# Trying to achieve dynamic Vertical ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, height, scrollview

I am using the storyboard to create a dynamic height UIScrollview. I followed this tutorial to create a Vertical UIScrollView with a set height.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg

Now that i've added all of my UI Elements, I'd like to make the view dynamic. Currently the height is set to 2000. I thought all I would need to do is sign `bottom view to container` to my ContentView and bottom uiview. but that produces no results.

I so far haven't had any luck in getting a dynamic height for the content view to work. I know this particular function is achievable but I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: can you show your code please

Comment: using autolayout set top,left,right,bottom 0 value in scrollview.after set your uiview in scollview than set your uiview constraint top,left,right,bottom,set fixed height.than after set horizontal center.than select uiview bottom contraint and set 0.try this step

Comment: All of this was done in the storyboard @Ram

Comment: you had to make outlet of scroollView and set the content size  as self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:width, height: height)